# bash - give each character in a file a random color

Tags: linux, bash

I have some ascii banners saved to plain text files that I use for different things and have used various ways to randomize the colors, but I haven't come up with a way to give every character a different color yet.  I'm thinking there's probably a way to do an array to make it happen, but can't seem to quite get there - I'm aware of things like toilet and lolcat but I'm not able to use those currently (using centos).  Here's what I've done so far:

change each file to a random color:

`echo -e "\e[38;5;$(shuf -i 1-255 -n 1)m$(<ascii/gc)\e[0m"`

you can do this with $RANDOM too:

`echo -e "\e[38;5;$(( $RANDOM % 256 ))m$(<ascii/gc)\e[0m"`

change each line in the file to a different color:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
echo -e "\e[38;5;$(shuf -i 1-255 -n 1)m${line}\e[0m";
done<ascii/gc
```

These files use multiple rows like so:

```
 $$$$$$\                            $$\        $$$$$$\  $$\                 $$\                     $$\
$$  __$$\                           $$ |      $$  __$$\ $$ |                \__|                    $$ |
$$ /  \__| $$$$$$\   $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$ |      $$ /  \__|$$$$$$$\   $$$$$$\  $$\  $$$$$$$\  $$$$$$\  $$ |
$$ |$$$$\ $$  __$$\ $$  __$$\ $$  __$$ |      $$ |      $$  __$$\ $$  __$$\ $$ |$$  _____|$$  __$$\ $$ |
$$ |\_$$ |$$ /  $$ |$$ /  $$ |$$ /  $$ |      $$ |      $$ |  $$ |$$ /  $$ |$$ |$$ /      $$$$$$$$ |\__|
$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |      $$ |  $$\ $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |$$ |      $$   ____|
\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$$ |      \$$$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |\$$$$$$  |$$ |\$$$$$$$\ \$$$$$$$\ $$\
 \______/  \______/  \______/  \_______|       \______/ \__|  \__| \______/ \__| \_______| \_______|\__|
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit the file and input the colorings at the places that you want.

Comment: For the particular example given, observe that each letter is 10 characters wide so you can easily determine which color to assign based on position.  In general, the difficult part of the problem is deciding which letter a given character is part of.

Comment: By "character" do you mean e.g. the giant "G" or each individual `$` and `\ `?

Comment: How do you plan on separating the ASCII-art block letters if not monospaced as in the example? Maybe pick a few points with random colors and interpolate every column in between for a gradient effect?

Comment: @thatotherguy every $, _ and \ in the file

Comment: @ChrisSchneider I don't think that works line by line, right? If you read the first line of a `U`, you wouldn't know if it is one letter or two.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider: Install [lolcat](https://github.com/jaseg/lolcat/). See also [here](https://think.unblog.ch/lolcat-fuer-mehr-farbe-im-terminal/) for usage examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply read character by character instead of line by line:

```
echo "Hello World" > file
# Read 1 character
while IFS= read -r -n 1 -d '' char; do
  # Write character without linefeed
  echo -ne "\e[38;5;$(shuf -i 1-255 -n 1)m${char}\e[0m";
done < file
```

This is faster and more robust with printf and RANDOM:

```
while IFS= read -r -n 1 -d '' c
do
  printf '\e[38;5;%dm%s\e[0m' "$((RANDOM%255+1))" "$c"
done < file
```

Comment: Wonderful!  I never realized read had so many options you can use with it, I'll have to read through them all soon, thank you!

Comment: I've found varying the number of characters affected can be fun too, and have tried this:  ```while IFS= read -r -n $((RANDOM%255+1)) -d '' c; do printf '\e[38;5;%dm%s\e[0m' "$((RANDOM%255+1))" "$c"; done<ascii/gc```

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation was printing each block letter in a different color. It required adding a separator to the input file (It looks the same, but I actually inserted [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) characters).

```
 $$$$$$\  ​          ​          ​      $$\ ​      ​ $$$$$$\  ​$$\       ​          ​$$\ ​          ​          ​$$\ ​
$$  __$$\ ​          ​          ​      $$ |​      ​$$  __$$\ ​$$ |      ​          ​\__|​          ​          ​$$ |​
$$ /  \__|​ $$$$$$\  ​ $$$$$$\  ​ $$$$$$$ |​      ​$$ /  \__|​$$$$$$$\  ​ $$$$$$\  ​$$\ ​ $$$$$$$\ ​ $$$$$$\  ​$$ |​
$$ |$$$$\ ​$$  __$$\ ​$$  __$$\ ​$$  __$$ |​      ​$$ |      ​$$  __$$\ ​$$  __$$\ ​$$ |​$$  _____|​$$  __$$\ ​$$ |​
$$ |\_$$ |​$$ /  $$ |​$$ /  $$ |​$$ /  $$ |​      ​$$ |      ​$$ |  $$ |​$$ /  $$ |​$$ |​$$ /      ​$$$$$$$$ |​\__|​
$$ |  $$ |​$$ |  $$ |​$$ |  $$ |​$$ |  $$ |​      ​$$ |  $$\ ​$$ |  $$ |​$$ |  $$ |​$$ |​$$ |      ​$$   ____|​    ​
\$$$$$$  |​\$$$$$$  |​\$$$$$$  |​\$$$$$$$ |​      ​\$$$$$$  |​$$ |  $$ |​\$$$$$$  |​$$ |​\$$$$$$$\ ​\$$$$$$$\ ​$$\ ​
 \______/ ​ \______/ ​ \______/ ​ \_______|​      ​ \______/ ​\__|  \__|​ \______/ ​\__|​ \_______|​ \_______|​\__|​
```

Then an `awk` one-liner can put color markings before and after each field, separated by the ZWS: `'\xe2\x80\x8b'`. It was necessary to use an external seed to get different colors at each run.

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM -F '\xe2\x80\x8b' 'BEGIN {srand(seed);} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(NR==1) {r[i]=int(rand()*255+1);} printf("\033[38;5;%dm%s\033[0m",r[i], $i);} printf("\n");}' ascii/gc
```

Here is the awk script expanded with comments:

```
BEGIN { # this block runs before processing the input
    srand(seed); # use the random seed passed via command line
}
{ # this block runs for each line
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { # this block runs for each field
        if(NR==1) { # this block runs for the first line only
            r[i]=int(rand()*255+1); # generate a color for the field
        }
        printf("\033[38;5;%dm%s\033[0m",r[i], $i); # print the escape codes and the field 
    }
    printf("\n"); # end of the line
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: random colored output from five runs]

Comment: This is not what I meant but I think it looks very good so thank you!  I've only used very basic uses of awk so if you could explain the command I would appreciate it

Comment: @ChrisSchneider Added a commented version.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you need to use color escape sequences with `echo -e`
And you can use `$RANDOM` is an internal Bash function (not a constant) that returns a pseudorandom [1] integer in the range 0 - 32767.

```
echo -e "\e[3$(( $RANDOM * 6 / 32767 + 1 ))mHello World!"
```